# GUI rogram connecting to SQL and listing information about products in specific category

Tags: java, sql, swing, awt

This is my very first application written in Java and so I finalized it, solely because it occurred to be my thesis.

---

It is a very simple program that lists categories (Northwind database is used as a template db) and as you one-click one it lists ID, Name and Price of all the products in this category in a table.

---

dbutils > DBConnection.java

```
package dbutils;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {
  public final static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  public final static String DB  = "northwind";
  private static Connection conn;
  public static Connection connect(String user, String password) throws SQLException
  {
      Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + DB, user, password);
      return c;
  }
}
```

myp > TableData.java

```
package myp;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableData extends AbstractTableModel
{
    public static Object[][] values = new Object[100][3];

    private final String[] Headers =
    {
      "ID", "Name", "Price"
    };

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return values.length;
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return values[0].length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return values[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public String getColumnName( int column)
    {
        return Headers[column];
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override 
    public boolean isCellEditable( int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

myp > Main.java

```
package myp;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
/* Компоненти на awt */
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

/*import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;*/
import java.sql.*;
import dbutils.DBConnection;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] labels     = new String[10];
        final int[] categoryID    = new int[10];

        String user     = "root";
        String password = "";
        String query1   = "SELECT CategoryName, CategoryID FROM categories";

        try
        (   Connection connection = DBConnection.connect(user, password);
            Statement  statement  = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet  resultSet  = statement.executeQuery(query1);
        )
        {
            System.out.println("Connection to db accomplished.");
            resultSet.beforeFirst();
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                labels      [resultSet.getRow()]    = resultSet.getString("CategoryName");
                categoryID  [resultSet.getRow()]    = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("CategoryID"));
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("SQL Code:" + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("SQL State:" + ex.getSQLState());
            System.err.println("Message:" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Product Explorer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        JList jlist = new JList(labels);

        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.EAST);

        TableData tableData = new TableData();
        JTable table = new JTable(tableData);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN);
        table.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));

        table.setDefaultRenderer(Float.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer());

        JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(table);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane2, BorderLayout.WEST);

        /**********************************************************************/
        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                JList theList = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
                int index = theList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());

                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    TableData.values = new Object[100][3];

                    String user     = "root";
                    String password = "";
                    String query    = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice FROM products WHERE CategoryID = " + index;

                    try
                    (
                        Connection connection = DBConnection.connect(user, password);
                        Statement  statement  = connection.createStatement();
                        ResultSet  resultSet  = statement.executeQuery(query);
                    )
                    {
                        resultSet.beforeFirst();
                        while(resultSet.next())
                        {
                            int i = resultSet.getRow();
                            TableData.values[i-1][0] = resultSet.getString("ProductID");
                            TableData.values[i-1][1] = resultSet.getString("ProductName");
                            TableData.values[i-1][2] = resultSet.getString("UnitPrice");
                            frame.validate();
                            frame.repaint();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex)
                    {
                        System.err.println("SQL Code:" + ex.getErrorCode());
                        System.err.println("SQL State:" + ex.getSQLState());
                        System.err.println("Message:" + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        jlist.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]